# Cordova 11 CORS Access-Control-Allow-Origin error during AJAX Call

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am developing an Android app using Cordova 11. The app performs AJAX call to 2 different domain URLs on the login page.

1. To validate the mobile number entered. If the number exists, it generates an OTP orelse says mobile number doesn't exist.
2. If the mobile number is valid, it generates a random 6 digit number and sends an SMS to that mobile number.

I have the below configuration:

```
> cordova -v
11.1.0

> cordova plugin
cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter 1.1.3 "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter"
cordova-plugin-androidx 3.0.0 "cordova-plugin-androidx"
cordova-plugin-file-opener2 4.0.0 "File Opener2"
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 2.0.0-dev "File Transfer"
cordova-plugin-file 7.0.0 "File"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 5.0.0 "InAppBrowser"
```

config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.camlinschool.cordova" version="2.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>Camlin School</name>
    <description>Camlin School App</description>
    <author email="abhilashhm15@gmail.com" href="#">
        Abhilash H M
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <icon src="www/images/school_logo.jpeg" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <access origin="http://68.178.168.127" />
    <access origin="https://api.onex-aura.com" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-navigation href="data:*" />
    <preference name="AndroidInsecureFileModeEnabled" value="true" />
    <preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
    <preference name="scheme" value="https" />
    <preference name="hostname" value="localhost" />
    <preference name="AndroidXEnabled" value="true" />
    <splash src="res/splashscreen.jpg" />
</widget>
```

The API calls used to work till two weeks ago, I even have the app on Playstore. But then while trying to add an image slider the build was failing. I removed and re-add android platform and it stopped working again.

1st AJAX call is to this domain http://68.178.168.127 on HTTP. The SMS trigger is to https://api.onex-aura.com domain on HTTPS.

On Chrome, only the SMS Trigger Ajax throws an error in the console:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.onex-aura.com/api/sms?key=XXXXX&to=XXXXXXX&from=CSHIGH&body=OTP' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

On the mobile app, even the mobile number verification AJAX call fails. But it just alerts saying "error" and no other details.

I even tried setting this in config.xml, but to no avail:

```
<preference name="scheme" value="http" />
<preference name="hostname" value="68.178.168.127" />
```

I don't see an option to attach the index.html to this post. I have uploaded it to my Google Drive and you can find it [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_GrIy_1ZQJDQwdQgNtQJpH7X8eGAAwrG/view?usp=drive_link). I have also uploaded the latest APK which fails [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EOdzLzOg6yWxy8t9wEQOFIS6jxu8xji_/view?usp=sharing). And the last working APK [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AVxr1qBg8y89iYjM_DxwZ1elXbzW603L/view?usp=sharing).

I have read close to 50 articles on this but none helps. Appreciate your help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really set

```
  <preference name="scheme" value="http" />
```

anymore since all content is now served via `https`, CORS is only supported via `https`

You need to upgrade your calls to https

```
   <preference name="scheme" value="https" />
```

and setup SSL for your host.

Comment: Hi @Eric, thanks for the response. So, you are saying that the call to http://68.178.168.127/ should happen over https? But my doubt is, the same was working just 2 weeks ago. But right after I readded Android platform, it stopped working. No changes in the code.

Comment: That's because you added a newer version of cordova-android, and content is now served to the webview via https (locally). So you can't do a post to http from a https webview. You need to upgrade to https for your host

Comment: Ok let me try that. Thank you so much.